# Do I have to file a tax return on a federal work study job?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I recently obtained a federal Work study job at my college. I filled out paper forms that were a bit obtuse to me. A I-9 form and a w-4 I think. I obtain $1200 maximum from this job. So do I have to fill out a tax return?

Comment: There isn't any special tax treatment for work study income, as far as I know. It's taxable income just like the wages from any other job. So the question of whether you have to file is simply determined by your total income for the year, as explained in the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The I-9 form is required because you are working. It is kept by the employer as proof that you have the proper documents to work. If the government was to inspect their records they can be fined if they don't have those document, in fact they have to keep them for several years after your employment is done.

A w-4 form is a federal tax form. There also was probably a state version of the form.  When you completed the w-4 it is used by your employer to determine how much in taxes need to be withheld. Employers don't know your tax situation. Even though you are on work study, you still could have made enough money over the summer to pay taxes.

But if this is your only job, and you will not make enough money to have to pay taxes, you can fill out the form as exempt. That means that last year you didn't make enough money to have to pay taxes, and you don't expect to make enough to have to pay taxes this year. If you are exempt, no federal income tax will be withheld. They might still withhold for social security and medicare. The state w-4 can also be used to be exempt from state taxes.

If they withhold any income taxes you have to file one of the 1040 tax forms to get that income tax money back. You will have to do so for the state income tax withholding.

A note about social security and medicare. If you have an on campus job, at the campus you attend, during the school year; they don't withhold money for social security and medicare. That law applies to students on work study jobs, and on non-work-study jobs.

[for single dependents](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p501/ar02.html#en_US_2014_publink1000220702) the federal threshold where you **must** file is:
>

> You **must** file a return if any of the following apply.
>
> 1. Your unearned income was more than $1,000.
> 2. Your earned income was more than $6,200.
> 3. Your gross income was more than the larger of—
>
>    a. $1,000, or
>
>    b. Your earned income (up to $5,850) plus $350.

Comment: Well I also did research and was paid for that, I had to fill out a I-9, but it was around 3-4k in total $ gained. Would that make me required to pay taxes

Comment: Im sorry if im a bit slow, but if the total income i will have obtained at the end of 2015 is 4700$, would that then be my earned income?

Comment: The income from the two jobs is your earned income. unearned income is items such as interest on your bank account.